# Time Skipping in VLC media player

Tags: vlc, libvlc, vlcj, libvlcsharp, vlc-android

I want something in VLC media player like subtitles file we add if we want to use it. But instead of subtitles i want to add time.

jump from-jump to

Example

2:00-3:00

5:00-7:80
Etc

If we add into video just like subtitles VLC media player jump from those times.

I really need this for children while watching movies. I can put time of some adult scenes to skip them.

I really appreciate for your help.

Comment: This is a feature request, not a Stackoverflow question. This should be posted on the vlc gitlab instead.

Comment: If you want to develop an app for that, though, you can use libvlc or one of its bindings (libvlcsharp and vlcj are two of them) and do that easily.